# Unit sphere intersected with hyperplanes, largest chamber?

Tags: geometry

I have a question which seems not that hard and maybe I can figure it out myself, but probably there is already a known theorem about it. Here it is:

Imagine the unit $n$-dimensional unit sphere is intersected by $n$ hyperplanes, passing through its center. These hyperplanes are slicing the sphere into $2^n$ parts. What is the easiest way to compare the sizes of these parts, to find which one is smallest/biggest? You can assume you are given the normal vectors to these hyperplanes and need to come up with a formula.

Comment: You were mistaken to think this was not that hard!

Answer (score 0):

In two dimensions, those sectins are proportional to the angle between the enclosing lines. In three dimension the section is proportional to the enclosed [solid angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_angle#Solid_angles_in_arbitrary_dimensions). This can be generalized with the n-dimensional solid angle.

Comment: Thank you for the response @flawr. For two dimensions it is indeed trivial. For three dimensions and higher though, I need several parameters for the computation. The solid angle formula calculates the area resulting from the intersection of the sphere with a cone (unless I missed something in the Wiki page).

Comment: I think the solid angle would be particularly useful if only bisected by a single hyperplane.

Comment: @RobertFrost But that is trivial, then you you just have two havles.

Comment: @ArturKirkoryan There are other formulae for polygons.

Comment: @flawr no, you would have an $n-1$ dimensional polytope. The question says $n$ hyperplanes. So in the case of a conventional sphere it's bisected by a pair of planes, with an unknown angle in-between and the peel of an obtuse orange-segment to measure the area of. The 3-sphere would have three planes, with I think six unknown angles.

Comment: But couldn't you easily compute those angles given the planes?

Comment: Yes but imagine 6, 5-dimensional volumes bisecting in a 6-dimensional space - which is the largest area between them?  There are 32 spaces created and a lattice of perhaps 120 different angles to compute.

Comment: @ArturKirkoryan use the formula for polygons if you have it. Since the shapes created are always a polygon with $n-1$ equally long sides and the last side of each shares the same curvature as the others.